# How to create turn-by-turn directions from a generic polyline route?

Tags: line, routing, navigation

I have some polyline data that represents a navigation route generated using Dijkstra's algorithm. Along this route I would like to calculate anytime a turn is required. Ideally, this would be some threshold where the route would require a turn greater than X amount.

Given a polyline, what are some techniques to calculate a turn and it's direction?

Bonus if any code samples are in C# or other C-style languages.

EDIT: Additional information to narrow the question down:

I am not using road data. The data is custom captured coordinates for a travel path. This means I can't use something that consumes road networks like from OSM data.

I believe I am looking for mathematical techniques to calculate the turns in my custom data. For example, I am currently using two segments of my path. Point1 -> Point2 and then Point2 -> Point3. With these two vectors I am trying to determine if there is an angle in direction change that could be considered a "turn". I am not sure of all the variables I need to take into account here with heading/bearing, etc. Any explanation of what to consider would help.

Comment: checkout Itinero, it is a C# project offering routing, turns, etc. You can use Open Street Map or other street networks.

Comment: Thanks @klewis. I added additional info that I am not using OSM data. I am using custom coordinates that represent "routes".

Answer (score 0):

This is called map matching. Use a gpx file and put it into a routing engine [like GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching).

Note: I'm one of the developers

Comment: I don't believe this will work for me because my data is not road data. It's a custom set of coordinates representing my travel areas. If I'm incorrect, let me know how GraphHopper would help. Apologies for not explaining that better in the question.